# c# Exceptions using Oauth2 with Google Drive API (using 4.0 .Net)

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using a code example at http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/ which would allow me to connect to the google drive api and get authorized using oauth2.  I downloaded the .json file that has my client id and client secret and put it in the \bin\debug output folder (and a few other places out of desperation) and when the code progresses to opening that file, it causes an exception which says 'stream handle' threw an exception of type 'System.Object.DisposeException'

The code throws an exception  here (at the credential line) when stepping through:

```html
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }
```

This is probably the 4th or 5th code example I have tried, and none of them seem to work. It is quite disheartening.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that that tutorial is very out of date.  I am not sure why you are unable to use stream reader to read the file.  But I think that you will find this code much cleaner and easer to understand.

```
string _client_id = "from apis console";
string _client_secret = "frome apis console";
string[] scopes = new string[] {DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                                DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
// here is where we Request the user to give us access, 
//    or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = 
        GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets {ClientId = _client_id,
                                                                 ClientSecret = _client_secret },
                                                    scopes,
                                                    Environment.UserName,
                                                    CancellationToken.None,
                                                new FileDataStore("Daimto.GooglePlus.Auth.Store")
                                                    ).Result;
```

I will update that tutorial ASAP.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me.  Even refreshed my client_secret, and I keep getting the same error:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

Comment: EDIT:  Still doesn't work for me.  Even refreshed my client_secret, and I keep getting the same error:  An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: One or more errors occurred.        ***  It doesn't matter if I press the "LoadFileDataStore" or "LoadSavedDataStore" (I changed the code in both to the one you provided above).  I also change Environment.UserName, back to "user" as well as change the string insde FileDataStore from your "Daimto.GooglePlus.Auth" back to the tutorial's Drive.Auth.Store. I am soooo confused.

Comment: Try this: Under references set each of the dll's to copy local true.  I updated the tutorial I have a Sample project to go along with it that I can upload to github.

Answer (score -1):

You are using an Async method to do your read. This is normally fine, but that means the code is still executing when you get to the end of your `using` statement. When the end bracket of the using is reached, the filestream is disposed while your async method is still trying to use it.

Try removing your using statement and instead disposing of the stream once your authorization is finished.

Comment: I tried your change and I still get the usual error, namely: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: One or more errors occurred.   (when I did deeper, I see the same 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in the stream).

Comment: Right after the method call, there is a call to the `Result` property, so that cannot be the reason.